# Do I need to cite the source every time I paraphrase in this particular project paper?

Tags: citations, citation-style, projects

This is my first question in this forum and although I have gained a lot of information about proper citation from the web, I am still confused in this case. We are assigned a task by college to make a study from resources available online on a particular topic and prepare a project.

Now, I know the fact that *I need to cite everytime I use someone else's idea*. But this project work has to be prepared in this order: Title, Abstract,
Keywords, Introduction, **Review of Literature**, Methodology, Results, Discussion, Conclusion,
Acknowledgement, References. This basically means that none of the work is our own and we need to study e-resources available and complete the task at hand.

What I am confused about is the particular heading called **Review of Literature**. I think that what we are going to write is entirely some sort of review of literature of others work since we've done nothing on our own. So, after making a thorough study of the papers available online, I paraphrased and put proper intext citations as well. Basically, methodology and results are also paraphrased from others work and as such I have put in-text citations not only in case of **Review of Literature** but also also in **Results** and **Methodology**.

So, I want to know whether I am doing it in the proper way or not?

This means, do I really need to provide in-text citations in this particular case in every part of the document if it is someone else's idea?

Sample:

> **REVIEW OF LITERATURE:**
> The study made by Gautret et al. (2020)  notes that hydroxychloroquine (an analogue of chloroquine) has been already demonstrated to have an anti-SARS-CoV-2 activity in vitro. Moreover, hydroxychloroquine’s clinical safety profile is better than chloroquine during long term use and also allows higher daily doses and interaction with other drugs is less as well (Gautret et al., 2020).

I have written the **Results** like this, but I think I've put too much in-text citation here:

> **Results:** Patients treated with hydroxychloroquine (6 out of which received supervised doses of azithromychin as well for initial five days) were aged an average of 51.7 years (~14 years older than mean age of control patients) but not much difference was seen between two groups regarding “gender, clinical status and duration of symptoms” (Gautret et al., 2020).
>
> As time passed, the study showed notable results and the percentage of patients showing negative PCR test of their swab samples at “days 3-4-5 and 6” during study period showed remarkable differences compared to “controls” when 70% of hydroxychloroquine treated patients were “virologically cured” but only a meager 12.5% of the other group achieved this feat (Gautret et al., 2020).

So, this brings me back all way round to the same question: **Do I need to cite each and everything which is not my own idea? And is the approach that I am taking correct?**

**Edit:**

This is what we are asked to do:

[image]

The Guidelines:

[image]

Comment: No such thing as citing too much. Better to be overcautious than not give credit for another's words or ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the use of many references for the review of literature which is to be expected as that is establishing the state of play at the moment.

In the methodology section you describe how your experiment will be carried out, possibly referring to another’s paper or experiment as a “support” or justification. But it is a description of your method, not someone else’s method so it is unlikely to need referencing.

Then, the results should be those from your work, and only your work as any references to the results of others will be in the discussion.

Then in the discussion you would compare your results with subsequent analysis with the results from others so references will be needed.

From what you show and what I understand is that you are referencing all the material for every section from others - where are your results, analysis and conclusions?

Comment: Thank you. ``From what you show and what I understand is that you are referencing all the material for every section from others`` - Yes, that is what I think we students are supposed to do. Because, we didn't do any of the work ourselves; but everything starting from the ``Review of Literature`` to ``Results`` is taken from other papers that are available online. We are told to make a thorough study of e-resources and then complete the project, nothing physical is needed to be done from our side apart from writing. So, referenced everything that I took from other papers. I hope I am clear:(

Comment: Am I doing the right thing for that case? I mean there was nothing to be done from our side apart from writing. We were asked to read the resources available and write the project in that particular order. So any idea that I wrote about in the paper is not mine but is taken from others' work :( Please elaborate.

Comment: @Sanu_012 It would seem, imho, that the only part you are doing is the review of literature and a discussion & analysis with a conclusion. As you don't do any experiment then you will not have results. Your best course of action is to discuss with the lecturer/professor.

Comment: I have written other parts of the paper as well but the things that I wrote under the heading of ``Review of literature``, ``Methodology``, ``Results`` and ``Discussion`` are entirely the works of others. I am editing the question to upload a snip about what we are asked to do, just to make it clear :(

Comment: @Sanu_012 so have you asked your lecturer/professor?

Comment: This is organised by the college authorities. They have just provided instructions to do this. I have not asked any of the professors till now. Should I?

Comment: Please have a look at the edited question. I have included the guidelines as well, but the only thing is that we are not going to do any physical work and we just need to write everything from online resources.

Comment: @Sanu_012 Based on the instructions, it looks like you're supposed to come up with your own methodology and results for this assignment. The methodology and results of others would entirely go into the "Review of literature" section. I think it's a relatively ambitious assignment.

Comment: How am I going to do that? I am not doing any experiment whatsoever :(

Comment: @Sanu_012 If you feel like your previous studies have not prepared you to do that kind of task, you should seek clarification with the lecturer/professor. For example, you could ask for existing samples for that kind of task.

Comment: You know what, they just want the completed work and clarify nothing more. No contact info to clarify doubts, nothing. I do not know how one can come up with his/her own results without doing an actual experiment or research. Is this even possible according to you?

Comment: @Sanu_012 how come you don't have contact info already? I used to know the building, room number and the names of all my professors and when they were likely to be in the office.

Comment: We are under lockdown for more than 70 days, everything is closed.

Comment: @Sanu_012 I even had the emails of the profs and email was new then. Comes down to commonsense. Plenty of communication is possible lockdown or not.

Comment: I have his whatsapp number. I tried texting him but he's not seen yet. Anything else, i should try?

Comment: @Sanu_012 Sounds like you've been given an unreasonable task with no way to seek clarification or guidance. I would escalate the situation (turn to the student union, department head etc.)

Answer (score 1):

When the source of a statement is unambiguously clear from the context, you don't have the give multiple references. Giving redundant references is not technically wrong, but stylistically not optimal, as it breaks the reading flow ("Yeah, I know that it's that particular study, you just said it in the previous sentence.")

I suggest to rewrite your sample 1 as follows:

> REVIEW OF LITERATURE: The study made by Gautret et al. (2020) notes that hydroxychloroquine (an analogue of chloroquine) has been already demonstrated to have an anti-SARS-CoV-2 activity in vitro. The authors find that hydroxychloroquine’s clinical safety profile is better than chloroquine during long term use, allows higher daily doses, and shows less interaction with other drugs.

Reading sample 2, I assume that there is some text between sample 1 and sample 2 (otherwise it's still the same context). In this case, I would keep the first reference, but still drop the second reference, as it's clear that both paragraphs refer to the same study. Actually, it might make sense to merge the paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That means I can use to 'the study' or 'the authors' to refer the work and get away without citing the source for that line?

Comment: @Sanu_012 Yes, exactly.